# Why is this differential equation's interval not (-$\infty$, $\infty$)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, continuity

I am currently using *A First Course in Differential Equations with Modeling Applications,* 10th Edition, by Dennis G. Zill.

> Section 2.3 Question #9. Find the general solution of the given differential equation. Give the largest interval $I$ over which the general solution is defined. Determine whether there are any transient terms in the general solution.
>
> The differential equation given was:
> $$
> x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = x^2 \sin(x)
> $$

Here is my work:

Divide by $x$ to get the standard form:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{1}{x} y = x \sin(x)
$$

Implement integrating factor:
$$
\mu = \exp\biggl(\int{-\frac{1}{x}}\,dx\biggr) 
= e^{-\ln(x)} = e^{\ln(x^{-1})} = \frac{1}{x}
$$

Multiply both sides by the integrating factor:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2}y = \sin(x)
$$

Notice the derivative of a product:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} \biggl[ y \, \frac{1}{x} \biggr] = \sin(x)
$$
Take the integral of both sides:
$$
\int \frac{dy}{dx} \biggl[ \frac{y}{x} \biggr] \, dx 
= \int \sin(x) \, dx 
\quad\implies\quad 
\frac{y}{x} = -\cos(x) + C
$$

Multiply both sides by $x$:
$$
y = -x\cos(x) + Cx 
\quad\text{or}\quad 
y = Cx - x\cos(x)
$$

My answer and the book's answer matched but the back of the book had $(0, \infty)$ as the interval. My question is why the interval is not $(-\infty, \infty)$ when $y$ is defined and continuous for all $x$.

Comment: Your first step was divide by x. Invalid on any interval containing 0.

Comment: @coffeemath, despite that, the solution is defined for all $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ and it satisfies the original ODE.

Comment: @Gonçalo You are missing the point. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea when it comes to solving the equation in closed form, but for finding the largest interval over which the ODE has a solution you need to write it as the IVP

$$y'(t)=F(t,y(t)):=t\sin(t)+y(t)/x \\ y(t_0)=y_0\tag{1}$$

Since $F$ is clearly continuous in its first argument and Lipschitz continuous in its second argument, there exists an open interval $I\subseteq \Bbb R$ where it has a well-defined solution.

By [standard theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Optimization_of_the_solution%27s_interval) of first order ODEs, the largest such interval is of the form $(t_0-\alpha,t_0+\alpha)$ where
$$\alpha=\min(a,b/M)$$

Here, $a$ and $b$ are the dimensions of the largest compact cylinder $C$ on which $F$ is defined, and $M=\sup_C |F|$. We can see that $F(\cdot, y)$ is defined $\forall y$, but, $F(0,\cdot)$ is undefined, therefore, we have
$$a=t_0~~,~~b=\infty$$

Therefore (assuming $t_0>0$, the case $t_0<0$ is analogous) given our initial condition at $t_0$, we have a well-defined solution on the interval $(0,2t_0)$. However, in general, we can make $t_0$ as large as we like, and thus there is no upper bound on the size of an interval on which we can have a valid solution, and thus the general solution is defined on the interval $(0,\infty)$.

---

But, you may ask, the closed form I found ($cx-x\cos x$) is defined on all of $\mathbb R$ : why does this not mean that the general solution of $(1)$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R$? This is because the one-parameter family of functions $\phi(\cdot;c):\mathbb R\to\mathbb R~~;~~\phi:(x;c)\mapsto cx-x\cos x$ is **NOT** one-and-the-same as the family of solutions to $(1)$. It happens to coincide with these general solutions on the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$, but **NOT** on all of $\mathbb R$, because $(1)$ is not well defined at the origin.

---

To give an illuminating example as to why we must restrict ODEs to simply-connected domains (in the case of $\mathbb R$, these are just intervals), consider the simple ODE

$$y'=0~~~\text{in}~~D  \tag {*}$$
Where $D=(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$.

Integrating the equation, we find that $y\equiv c$ is (or, to be precise, *should be*) constant. **HOWEVER**, one may observe that the function
$$u(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x>0 \\ 0 & x<0\end{cases}$$
Satisfies the ODE $(*)$ in the domain $D$, but *is not constant*. The point is, if we allow our domain to be disconnected, there will be many solutions that our standard techniques (e.g integration) will miss, and all of the notions of existence and uniqueness will be utterly destroyed.